# Confusion about time borrowing

Tags: fpga, vlsi

After studying timing analyzing in FPGA I still have some confusions about time borrowing like the following:

1. I have seen some of this site EE having good reputation saying that time borrowing is only for VLSI not FPGA while in Quartus document explaining timing constraints time borrowing is discussed.
2. Does time borrowing need any configurable material? In fact, what I first understood is that the fact of considering latch with level instead of edge sensitive clock is sufficient to benefit from time borrowing since if for instance we have latch1 sensistive to level 1 applied to latch2 sensitive to level 0 then if the combinatoric circuit in latch1 has a delay higher than the level 1 width but the combinatoric circuit in latch2 has delay less than the level 0 width minus what exceeds from latch1 circuit than timing constraints are ok by time borrowing. What is more confusing for me is that I have found a Patent on a configurable delay for time borrowing (so added hardware needed).

Could someone explain this to me please.

Comment: Someone upvoted my post and another one downvoted it. The one who downvoted it must of course have the answer and find it obvious. Maybe a comment would be helpful if he has no time to answer.

Comment: The Xilinx UltraScale+ FPGAs definitely support time borrowing, they have a programmable delay at the leaf clock buffer level to support it and I have seen Vivado use it. I have never seen this use a latch, only normal clocked DFFs although I think it can create latches too. Can't answer for Intel FPGAs though.

Comment: Better to avoid latches under normal circumstances and go for flip flops since they make timing analysis similar and give easier to predict behaviour